# How to restore an unknown type BLOB field from Firebird

Tags: blob, firebird, compression

I am trying to restore a BLOB field stored in a Firebird database, and the only information I have is that the content of the BLOB field is a document.

I've tried using IBManager to right-click on the cell and click "Save BLOB to file", but the saved file is unreadable (as if it was encrypted). I tried to open it with Microsoft Word, notepad, adobe etc, with no success. I also tried opening it with WinRAR (I thought that it might have been compressed before being stored to the database) but still nothing.

Is there a way to find out whether and how the BLOB file was compressed, and how to restore it?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

I have converted the firebird database to SQL and I use the following code to extract the Unencoded BLOB documents:

```
         conn.Open();
        dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            byte[] document_byte = null;

            if (dr[1] != System.DBNull.Value)
            {
                document_byte = (byte[])dr[1];
            }

            string subPath = "C:\\Documents\\" + dr[0] + "\\";
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);

            if (document_byte != null)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(subPath + "Document", document_byte);
            }

        }
```

How can I adjust my code to decode the BLOB file from Base64 since I know is Base64 encoded?

Comment: Could you post the first few bytes as hex (say 10 - 20), maybe someone recognizes the filetype.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel

Here are the first bytes of the file. 

 'eJztnQmATuX+x3/vMu+872xmGPtgkpBlDAaTpcaSpRiUbEm2GTNjDIZU/mHqCimuypbrWrLeSJa6JIUSSt0oqaSuuu1XqIvcwvy/z1nmnPO+5zzv4sxi7nn4zFmec37P8nv25bxHPog7tWprja/Iy9xKDrpa6CGX6p4dHJcvYok+xcEGrhYWFrJbx8DHoNAy1405vXYfTRjmcRJdqrinSLMwUHz'

Comment: That looks like a base64 encoding to me. Have you tried to decode it first?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that now with no success..

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I just updated my question above. Could you have a look? thanks...

Comment: Use [FromBase64Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.frombase64transform.aspx) or [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Unless the field uses BLOB filter the data is stored into database as is, ie Firebird doesn't alter it in any way. Check the field's definition, if it does have `SUB_TYPE 0` (or `binary`) then it is "ordinary" binary data, ie Firebird doesn't apply any filter to it. And even in case the field uses some filter, unless there is a bug in the filter code you should get the original data back when reading the content of the BLOB.

So it comes down to the program which stored the document into DB, it is quite possible that it compressed or encrypted the file, but there is no way Firebird can help you to figure out what algorithm was used... One option would be to save the content of the BLOB into file and then try the *nix [`file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) command, perhaps it is able to detect the file format used.

I would also check the DB for corruptions, just for case (Firebird's `gfix` command line tool).

Comment: I tried your suggestion using a tool for Windows but it does not recognize the file. Thanks for your time anyway!